# Why is any number assignable to Enum types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
enum ResponseStatus {
    BAD_REQUEST = 400,
    INTERNAL_SERVER = 500
}

const status: ResponseStatus = -122;
```

I can assign any number to `status` and no error is generated, although `status` is of type `ResponseStatus` which can be either `400` or `500`.

So what is the point of restricting `status` to the `ResponseStatus` type if I can assign any number to it anyway?

This behavior does not happen with enums if the values are strings.

Why is this implemented in TypeScript this way?

If I restrict something to a type I expect to not be able to assign stuff that is not compatible with that type.

Please provide a simple example if you can, which explains the reason for this. I read something online that it has something to do with bitwise operators but I really didn't understand what and where it is useful.

Comment: also see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6131

Comment: Enums are just glorified integers with names and @SuperStormer is correct this is a duplicate question